# A program for Primality Test for very large numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

I need to test if a number is a prime number.
Is there any program to test very large numbers like the biggest one with 17,425,170 digits ?
I know about the Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search (GIMPS) project but I am not searching prime numbers. I just want to test them.

Comment: When you're asking about such a well-documented problem and you don't find the existing material on the Web accessible, it makes sense to point out in your question what part of e.g. [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) on the topic you don't understand. Else people can only guess what your problem is and would effectively have to write another explanation all over again of something that's already been well explained many times. (If by "program" you mean concrete software, you'll find some in the "External Links" section of that article.)

Comment: I don't get which one is the fastest primality test.

Comment: If I knew which one is the fastest I could try to implement that algorithm but the problem about how long the test will take to run on my computer still remains. Is it a matter of 1 year or 10 years ?

Comment: Do you want to fing a record prime, or do you just want to find primes with, lets say, $20,000$ digits ? Do you want to find primes with a special form, or random primes ?

Comment: If you are content with a probable prime, you can get results with PARI/GP in a reasonable time, but it you want very large proven primes, they must have a special form. Otherwise it takes very long to find such a prime.

Comment: @Peter What I want to do is give a very large number in input to this program and get a precise answer -> prime or not prime. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question: I don't want to find prime numbers, I just want to test if  a specific number is prime. The problem is that my number is very large.

Comment: How many digits does your number have ?

Comment: For example 20,000,000 digits. Is there any program that will support a number with so many digits ?

Comment: This is larger than the current record! I do not know such a program, but there should be some. If the number has no special form, it is hopeless to acutually prove the primality.  Join in PrimeGrid, this could be what you want. In principle, PARI/GP could do this calculation, but is far too slow for such numbers!

Comment: Before testing, if your number is prime, you should begin with trial division. Perhaps, there is a small prime factor (Lets say, $10$  or less digits) and you can save much time!

Comment: I get your point. I thought there was some kind of program (or library) that supports infinite amount of digits and is limited only by computing power and disk space.

Comment: @vovahost  "infinite amount of digits" ? You probably mean something like $10^9-10^{12}$ digits.

Comment: Yeah something that big. I had some theories about how prime numbers were distributed and needed to also test it on large numbers. Long story short: It didn't work. I was thinking that maybe by large amounts of test I could find a way to predict the next prime number but nothing happened ;).